# Enlarging interlinear space to avoid cluttered text at specific lines

Tags: line-spacing

I am using the `mtpro2` typefaces in a document and I have noticed that where a superscript appears on the vertical relative to a subscript in the line immediately above, the vertical space between the top of the former and the bottom of the latter is, at least to my taste, too small. There is no collision indeed but the text becomes too cluttered and unless the page is magnified it looks like there is actually glyph collision. Other than that, line spacing is just fine.

I wonder if it is possible to somehow inform the system to set a larger interline space at those points without having to enlarge the space everywhere.

EDIT:

I have found that this is not an effect of the typeface but rather of my usage of a command of my own. Check in the below MWE that the leading between the first two lines is larger than between the last two lines, where I use my own 
commands. With the `mtpro2` typeface there is almost a glyph collision.

I have found that by switching the location of the token '^' according to the definion of the command `\trianglesubx` (see below), the leading is fine. What is the reason?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xparse,amsfonts}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\trianglesub
  { s O{N} O{o} }
  { \bigtriangleup^{\IfBooleanT{#1}{#3}}_{#2} }

\DeclareDocumentCommand\vsuper
  { m m }
  {\mathbb{#1}^{#2}}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\trianglesubx
  { s O{N} O{o} }
  { \bigtriangleup\IfBooleanT{#1}{^{#3}}_{#2} }


\begin{document}
\noindent$\bigtriangleup_{N}$\\$\mathbb{R}^{N}$

\noindent$\trianglesub[N]$\\$\vsuper{R}{N}$

\noindent$\trianglesubx[N]$\\$\vsuper{R}{N}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have provided no example, but the linespacing is specified separately by your documentclass in its definition of `\normalsize`, `\small` etc, so you need to modify those settings, the details depending on the original definitions.

As a quick fix that would apply to any documentclass you could use

```
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.1}
\selectfont
```

To increase baselines by 10%

For example the standard classes at 10pt define normalsize via

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
%                                ^^^^^^
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
```

where the marked argument specifies that at `\normalsize` a 12pt baseline is used.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please see my EDIT. I have realized that the effect is related to my own commands and not to the typeface.